# Loop array in ajax

Tags: arrays, ajax, loops

In order to preload my website, I'm trying to loop an array in Ajax to see the percentage loaded of my 3 images but no percentage is displayed, only this text on the page !

[image]

Is it an encoding problem ? I've used this JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/r86gM/ .

Here is my page of test with 1 jpg : http://piecesdetheatre.free.fr/tests/test.html % ok

Here is my page of test with 3 jpg : http://piecesdetheatre.free.fr/tests/test2.html % not ok

I'm a beginner. Any ideas why this happens? Thank you for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>ajax percentage</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" ></script>

 
  
</head>
<body>
    <div id="progressCounter"></div>
<br>
<div id="loading">Loading</div>
<br>
<div id="data"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
array = ['gogol','labiche','courteline'];

for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
//var id = array[i];
//console.log(id + array[i]);
var progressElem = $('#progressCounter');
var URL = "http://piecesdetheatre.free.fr/img/" + array[i] + ".jpg";
$("#loading").hide();
$("#progressCounter").append(URL);


$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: URL,
    cache: false,
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);//affiche le code source
        alert(thrownError);
    },
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        //Download progress
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
               document.getElementById("progressCounter").innerHTML =
            this.responseText;
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#loading').show();
    },
    complete: function () {
        $("#loading").hide();
    },
    success: function (json) {
        $("#data").html("data receieved");
    }
});
}

  //]]></script>

  

    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few pointers (may not answer your question completely)

Your ajax response is an image. So `dataType` should not be JSON, if its json jQuery will try to parse the JSON response. In your case its not JSON, so it will throw error.

Try  `dataType: 'text'`, or remove that key value pair.

> document.getElementById("progressCounter").innerHTML =
> this.responseText;

You are trying to provide image data to an html element. Thats what you see in the image.

Try this instead

```
document.getElementById("progressCounter").innerHTML = evt.total
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps me to get my percentage.
If I write console.log(evt.total); I get tens of different values. Why ? I should get only the total weight of all my images ?

Comment: @user14387116 Thats because you are loading multiple images and for each image the progress is different.  You are showing the progress of multiple images in the same div, so the progress percentage will keep on changing until all image progress is 100%

Comment: A detail : when I run test.html or test2.html, while half a second I see the ulrl's image(s), is it possible to display 0% instead ?

Comment: @user14387116 Thats because of this line `$("#progressCounter").append(URL);` remove and check

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `append`

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){//var id = array[i];
//console.log(id + array[i]);
var URL = "<p>http://piecesdetheatre.free.fr/img/" + array[i] + ".jpg</p>"; $("#loading").hide();
$("#progressCounter").append(URL);
```

Comment: can you check now?

Comment: no percentage, have a look on the results http://piecesdetheatre.free.fr/tests/test3.html

Comment: you didn't forget </p> in var URL ?

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried this code. Is it correct ?

```
var idArray = ['gogol.jpg' , 'ionesco.jpg' , 'williams.jpg'];
for(var i = 0;i < idArray.length;i++) {
    (function(i) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // ***
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://piecesdetheatre.free.fr/img/' + idArray[i]);
        //xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authorizationToken);
        xhr.send(null);
        console.log(xhr.readyState);
        xhr.onprogress = function (event) {
        console.log('LOADING', xhr.readyState); // readyState will be 3
        console.log( Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100) +"%");
};
     
    })(i);
}
```